# How to read a file with comma separated integers in bash

Tags: bash

I am fairly new to bash, and I have been trying to figure out how to read numbers from a file for example data.txt or data.csv into a file named calc.bash.

I have the interface working, but I am stuck on how to read numbers into calc.bash so I can make the calculations work. I would also like to know how to hold the position of the 2 numbers that I choose to either +-*/ and then use another operation for more numbers.

For example.

we have a list of numbers 1,3,4,6,10,12END in data.txt
I read 1 and 3 and I add them together.
How do I save the place of where I last left off so I can do another operation with number 4. So 1+3 = 4 then 4 + 4 = 8 then if I want to substract it will be 8-6 all the way until I hit END. But only if they choose to do it .

if they choose not to have the previous number +-*/ with the next. You move on to the next 2 numbers in the list. So if you are done with 1,3 then you move on to 4,6

This is what my CalcUI.bash Looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  read -p "Enter operation to be performed (+-/ or Q to Quit): " op
  case $op in
    [+]   ) echo "You chose +"; echo "+" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    [-]*  ) echo "You chose -"; echo "-" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    [*]   ) echo "You chose *"; echo "*" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    [/]*  ) echo "You chose /"; echo "/" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    [Qq]* ) exit;;
    *     ) echo "Please answer using the following +-/ or Q to Quit";;
  esac
done
while true; do
  read -p "Use previous result as operand?(y/n): " pr
  case  $pr in
    [Yy]  ) echo "You chose y";echo "y" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    [Nn]* ) echo "You chose n";echo "n" >> Inst.txt; break;;
    *     ) echo " Please answer using y or n";;
  esac
done
while true; do
  read -p "Reset data file pointer to start of data file?(y/n) " reset
 case $reset in
   [Yy]  ) echo "You chose y"; break;;
   [Nn]* ) echo "You chose n"; break;;
   *     ) echo "Enter y or n";;
  esac
done
exec ./Calc.bash &
```

This is what the CalcUI.bash looks likes

```
Running CalcUI:
Enter operation to be performed (+-*/ or Q to Quit): *
Use previous result as operand? (y/n): n
Reset data file pointer to start of data file? (y/n):n

Calc.bash run on Tue Apr 4 14:46:24 CDT 2017  process id 2493
Calculated result for: 3 * 35
Result: 105

press <enter> to continue
```

Im having trouble figuring out how to communicate `calc.bash` with `data.txt` and `calc.bash` with `calcUI.bash`.

Comment: hello and welcome on SO, what have you tried so far? Can you provide a minimal concise example of what you've done and that shows where you stuck at?

Comment: I updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use functions.
When you do everything in one file, it is easier to see what is happening.
You can make utilities in separate files later, and `source thatfile` to have environment settings available in the caller.
Most times I use functions I return the results using `echo` (and call `my_function` with `my_result=$(my_function)`). This will fail when you write something else to the console. You can use global variables.

Reading the integers as fields can be implemented by replacing the `,` with newlines (use `tr`).
A solution could look like

```
function get_operator {
   while true; do      
   read -p "Enter operation to be performed (+-/ or Q to Quit): " op
   case $op in                                                      
       [+] ) echo "You chose +";break;;                             
      [-] ) echo "You chose -";break;;                              
      [*] ) echo "You chose \*, (not supported yet) try again";;    
      [/] ) echo "You chose /";break;;                              
       [Qq] )exit;;                                                 
       * ) echo "Please answer using the following +-/ or Q to Quit";;
      esac                                                            
exit
    done
}

function get_next_operator {
   while true; do
      read -p "Use previous result as operand?(y/n): " pr
      case  $pr in
      [Yy] ) break;;
      [Nn] ) echo "You chose n";get_operator; break;;
      *) echo " Please answer using y or n";;
      esac
   done
}

unset first_integer
unset op
for k in $(echo "2,4,6,8,9" | tr ',' '\n'); do
   echo "Next integer = $k"
   if [ -z "${first_integer}" ]; then
      first_integer=$k
      continue
   fi
   if [ -z "${op}" ]; then
      get_operator
   else
      get_next_operator
   fi
   printf "%s %s %s = " "${first_integer}" "${op}" "${k}"
   (( first_integer = first_integer $op k ))
   printf "%s\n" "${first_integer}"
done
```